# API Call error: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, api, error-handling, connection, database-connection

Sometimes when I call API there is an error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

But when I re-run the chunk several times, it works. Do you know where is the problem or how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions that are needed to call API.

Comment: I have permission